# Wrong limit with Maxima CAS

Tags: maxima

This very simple limit:

```
(%i1) limit((z^(2*n)-1)/(z^2-1),z,-1);
(%o1)                              infinity
```

goes catastrophically wrong. We can think that a reasonable solution will be

```
(%i1) declare(n,integer);
(%o1)                                done
(%i2) limit((z^(2*n)-1)/(z^2-1),z,-1);
(%o2)                                  0
```

And wrong again! BTW all (well, actually I haven't checked all, :-)) the particular cases are correct:

```
(%i1) limit((z^(2*99)-1)/(z^2-1),z,-1);
(%o1)                                 99
```

More mystery: the function is even and the other limit

```
(%i1) limit((z^(2*n)-1)/(z^2-1),z,1);
(%o1)                                  n
```

**Is OK!** (even without the declare) *Why?*

Comment: I'm sorry you've run into a bug. I think a more appropriate forum for this bug report is the Maxima bug tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/